# How to find the length of each element stored in an array separated by comma and to check the first digit of it

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

How to find the length of each element stored in an array separated by comma and to check the first digit of it...Here is the code:

```
Sub validation()

    Dim acc_validation As String
    Dim acc_no As Variant, i As Integer
    Dim flag1

    flag1 = False

    acc_validation = Range("I7").Value

    acc_no = Split(acc_validation, ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(acc_no)
        If (Len(acc_no(i) <> 16)) Then
            If (flag1 = False) Then
                MsgBox "Please enter the correct account number"
                flag1 = True
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Show us some sample data and tell us what your code isn't doing that is should, any error messages and example of the desired output. Also, highlight all your code and press ctrl + k to insert it properly within a code box. And make what you are asking clear. A question normally has ? at the end for example.

Answer (score 0):

To get the length and the first digit of your element you try this:

```
For i = 0 To UBound(acc_no)
    MsgBox "Length: " & Len(acc_no(i)) & " First digit: " & Left(acc_no(i), 1)
    If (Len(acc_no(i) <> 16)) Then
        If (flag1 = False) Then
            MsgBox "Please enter the correct account number"
            flag1 = True
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Hope this helps!